# visual studio show mysql table does not exist

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio

I have visual studio 2015 which connect MySql database stored procedure to get data 
to get data from table. Now I always encounter an error

```
Error occurs in the 'Data.MySQLDataProvider.GetCodeByTypeAndName' method.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Table 'test.Codes' doesn't exist
```

But I cannot connect to mysql through workbench and I can see the table using the same account information in visual studio. What I can see is that the table name is in Capital Letter "Code", however the table name in my remote server is in small letter "code". I am running MySQL in Ubuntu and running  Visual Studio in Windows. Is there any config related to the letter case of table name or other issues I should cater?

Comment: can't you just show tables in your Ubuntu mysql server with the mysql cli?

Comment: @LeGEC Yes. The Codes is with an s at the end

Comment: @mingchau Yes, I can show the tables;

Comment: I set lower_case_table_names = 1 in mysqld.conf and restart mysql in Ubuntu. Then the problem is solved.